# Installing cabinet on a wall with a hump in it

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, carpentry

I am installing SEKTION cabinets from Ikea and there is a hump in one of the walls. The adjacent cabinet wall is straight. The backsplash will most likely be subway tiles, I would like to go with large tiles but with this hump I don't think it's possible anymore. The flooring is vinyl plank so no grout lines.

Pictured below is the kitchen without the uppers. Highlighted green is where the hump is located. There will be either a large filler piece or small shelves that sit between the corner cabinet and 36" sink cabinet.

[image: The kitchen without upper cabinets displayed, highlighted green is where the hump is located.]

I concluded several options,

**Option 1)** I have considered carving out the drywall to remove the hump but it sits very closely to a window. Not sure if I would be able to blend it well.

**Option 2)** There is a corner cabinet joining the two walls together, so I would have to compensate for 3/8" on both sides. Unfortunately the corner cabinet would pitch the straight wall and I would have to angle the rest of the cabinets on that wall.

[image: Balancing the straight edge on the hump]

**Option 3)** Put a huge 3/4" shim on the sink cabinet that sits directly under the window and let the countertop guys handle it. The sink cabinet depth from the wall becomes 25" instead of 24" like the rest of the cabinets. There will also be a cabinet & panel over the fridge, might pull it out too far.

[image: Cabinet if I shimmed it out 3/4"]
[image: Proper cabinet depth on a straight wall]

Comment: What kind of countertop will you have installed? Some can be created with arbitrary depth, so 25 inches instead of 24 is no big deal, no extra cost, and adapts to imperfect wall profile easily. Other kinds are pre-manufactured for precisely 24 inch depth and expect nearly-straight walls.

Comment: @GregHill I wanted to go with prefab to save money but I might have to go with a custom stone now that's slightly larger. The counter top guy has not been able to make it here yet to give me a quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount the cabinet square to the room.

the splashback will hide some amount of crack, basically the thickness of your tile plus half the depth of your thinset trowel teeth.

If necessary trim the benchtop to acommodate the hump.

Comment: By square to the room you mean just add a 3/4" shim to the one cabinet that's out of level? Everything else is perfectly square besides this one cabinet under the window.

Comment: yeah, if you put them in crooked it will show, and you'll end up regretting it.

Comment: Gotcha, the cabinet is now 25" away from the wall instead of 24" but it is square to the corner cabinet. The countertop guy should be able to handle this.

Comment: This is the right answer, *as long as* the countertop guy really is able to handle this. You should talk to him first.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon my post, this was the right answer. The countertop installer said it's completely normal and that everything looks great.